# My discord bot is reacting to a command that I deleted

Tags: python, discord.py

I need help with my discord bot, I actually never done one before. I wanted to do a command that sends in a loop a certain amount of messages (the number is passed to the command as argument). This is the command :

```py
@bot.command(name='mass', help='sends a certain ``amount`` of messages')
async def mass(ctx, amount=10):
    for i in range(int(amount)):
        await ctx.send(f'Message no{i}')
```

When I execute it, the bot sends twice each message, like if another instance of the bot was executing it.

So I tried to remove it, but the bot is responding with one message per number even if he can't found it. I have this message on the shell :

```
Ignoring exception in command None:
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "mass" is not found
```

Comment: Seems like you still have a bot running and only restarted one of them without the command? The other one that still runs still have the command defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running `ps aux | grep python` and see if you have multiple scripts running. It should look something like this

```
user     1234   0.0  0.3  567  891 s003  S+    2:35PM   0:00.42 python3 bot.py

user     1235   0.0  0.3  567  891 s003  S+    2:35PM   0:00.42 python3 bot.py
```

if there are more than run then do

```
sudo kill -9 1234
```